# How do I (optionally) pipe text into a Turtle shell script?

Tags: haskell-turtle

I am working on a [Turtle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.5.23/docs/Turtle-Tutorial.html) based shell script. I'd like it to be able to, optionally, accept piped in text in place of an argument. After reading the docs and playing with the `stdin` Turtle function to no avail, I realize I'm stuck.

Is something like this supported by Turtle? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is 'no' it is not supported by Turtle. But it **is** supported by Haskell. Here's how I did it:

```
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
    gotPipedInText <- hReady stdin
    case gotPipedInText of
        True -> do
            message <- getContents
            putStr message
        False -> putStr "nothing piped in\n"
```

The key insight for me is that I need to check for the existence of the piped in text before trying to read it, as reading an 'empty' handle blocks while waiting for input, but reading a 'full' handle gets the existing content.